# Want to increase the size of anchor element, but not of the anchor itself with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to increase font size of the a and p elements, but itself, an element for increasing the font is an anchor element so it increases with the press, but this is false and cant happen.

HTML:

```
<div class="fontsize">
<a class="fontSizePlus" href="#">A+</a>
|
<a class="fontReset" href="#" style="font-size: 17px;">Reset</a>
|
<a class="fontSizeMinus" href="#" style="font-size: 17px;">A-</a>
</div>
```

So far I tried various targeting solutions like:

```
var elm = $('p, a:not("a.fontSizePlus")');
```

apparently with no luck.

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    //min font size
    var min=9;  

    //max font size
    var max=16; 

    //grab the default font size
    var reset = $('p').css('fontSize'); 

    //font resize these elements
    var elm = $('p, a:not("a.fontSizePlus")');  

    //set the default font size and remove px from the value
    var size = str_replace(reset, 'px', ''); 

    //Increase font size
    $('a.fontSizePlus').click(function() {

        //if the font size is lower or equal than the max value
        if (size<=max) {

            //increase the size
            size++;

            //set the font size
            elm.css({'fontSize' : size});
        }

        //cancel a click event
        return false;   

    });

    $('a.fontSizeMinus').click(function() {

        //if the font size is greater or equal than min value
        if (size>=min) {

            //decrease the size
            size--;

            //set the font size
            elm.css({'fontSize' : size});
        }

        //cancel a click event
        return false;   

    });

    //Reset the font size
    $('a.fontReset').click(function () {

        //set the default font size 
         elm.css({'fontSize' : reset});     
    });

});

//A string replace function
function str_replace(haystack, needle, replacement) {
    var temp = haystack.split(needle);
    return temp.join(replacement);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Could you create a fiddle for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i totally understand what you're asking for...

Here's a link to a fiddle with it set up

http://jsfiddle.net/mkyzP/

All seems to work fine.

You just need to make sure to change

```
var elm = $('p, a:not("a.fontSizePlus")');
```

To

```
var elm = $('p, a:not("a.fontSizePlus, a.fontReset, a.fontSizeMinus")');
```

So that none of the links shrink or grow.

Alternatively you could just change the a tags to span tags.